# jQuery - separate onClick event for each word in a paragraph

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I want to allow viewers of my page to click any word in a paragraph to trigger a tooltip (like a word definition, or some other event) but I don't want to bloat my html with tags wrapped around each word.

The effect I'm going for is similar to what the New York Times does in their articles. Double-clicking any word in a NYT article makes a tooltip appear, which can be clicked for more info. [Example.](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/09/06/business/global/reluctantly-europe-inches-closer-to-a-fiscal-union.html?hp&_r=0) But you'll notice in the source there's no markup in the original page for those tooltips.

Can this be achieved with jQuery? something like, onclick any word?

Answer (score 1):

it's actually not on click, it's on selection I think.

Take a look on [this](http://www.aakashweb.com/resources/pages/demos/jquery-selected-text-sharer/) plugin.

**Update:**

Also I found similar discussion on ths stackoverflow: [Tooltip triggered by text selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362297/tooltip-triggered-by-text-selection)

Comment: this looks like the right start. i think the "Tooltip triggered by Text selection" method has two advantages: (a) it can be triggered both by doubleclick and by dragging a text selection, and (b) it can limit which words trigger the tooltip. That's important because I will want to assign different tooltip content to certain phrases and possibly to each word. 

Much thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to make it like this:

```
var openTag = "<a href='#' onclick='javascript:wordAction(this)'>";
var closeTag = "</a>"

var paragraph = $("#paragraph");
var newParagraphHtml = paragraph.html().replace(" ", closeTag + openTag + " ");
paragraph.html(openTag + newParagraphHtml + closeTag);

var wordAction = function(el) {
    var word = el.html();  
    // do wat you want with your word
}
```

Regards