# Display Social icons on selection

Tags: html, css, icons, social-networking

On The Guardian website (e.g. [this article](http://www.theguardian.com/film/2015/oct/21/spectre-review-james-bond-is-back-stylish-camp-and-sexily-pro-snowden)) there is a neat feature where when I select any text with my mouse social media icons appear beneath it which allow me to tweet or email my selection.

How can I replicate this?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302683/how-to-create-tooltip-over-text-selection-without-wrapping) question and you will get idea of how can that be achieved