# How to add a tooltip to a selection?

Tags: draftjs, draft-js-plugins, react-draft-wysiwyg

When the users selects some text, I want to be able to show a tooltip, right below the selected text?
Any ideas how can I do that?

Comment: This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65503896/4186857) might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a component that creates the tooltip, such as paper-tooltip, or create one, even with css only, depends on your usecase.

[Here is a W3 example of a CSS tooltip](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, [`react-draft-wysiwyg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-draft-wysiwyg) does not support [arbitrary plugins](https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg/issues/456#issuecomment-330917677) in the same way that [`draft-js-plugins`](https://github.com/draft-js-plugins/draft-js-plugins) does.

Searching on NPM, the only text selection related plugin I found is [`draft-js-delete-selection-plugin`](https://github.com/lonord/draft-js-delete-selection-plugin). You could use that as a starting point, as well as look at the documentation for [SelectionState](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-selection-state).

Answer (score 0):

Without any idea of what you have so far it is hard to provide more info. I have created a JS fiddle that shows a simple tool tip with an event listener that gets the selected text by element id
https://jsfiddle.net/03Lu28qb/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  const textSelectionTooltipContainer = document.createElement("div");
  textSelectionTooltipContainer.setAttribute(
   "id",
   "textSelectionTooltipContainer"
 );
textSelectionTooltipContainer.innerHTML = `<p id="textSelected">Selected! </p>`;
const bodyElement = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];


bodyElement.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
  var textu = document.getSelection().toString();
  if (!textu.length) {
  textSelectionTooltipContainer.remove();
}
});

document
 .getElementById("textToSelect")
 .addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
  let textu = document.getSelection().toString();
  let matchu = /\r|\n/.exec(textu);
  if (textu.length && !matchu) {
    let range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
    scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    containerTop = scrollPosition + rect.top - 50 + "px";
    containerLeft = rect.left + rect.width / 2 - 50 + "px";
    textSelectionTooltipContainer.style.transform =
      "translate3d(" + containerLeft + "," + containerTop + "," + "0px)";
    bodyElement.appendChild(textSelectionTooltipContainer);
   }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to do it in react try [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip).
If you trying to do it in js try [this](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tooltip.asp).