# Tooltip/Hovermenu on textselection only (that follows cursor)

Tags: javascript, html, css

This webpage:
https://www.fastcompany.com/90338940/this-is-why-no-one-responds-to-your-email
appends a "hover button" only on textselection that moves with the cursor.

I found a CSS hover menu,

```
<style>.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;}
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;}
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {visibility: visible;}</style>
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

but that is certainly dissimilar from the result achieved here.

So my question is:

How does one achieve such "hover" tip that only appears when text is marked and follows the selection cursor around ?

Edit:
This looks like a solution..
[How to create tooltip over text selection without wrapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302683/how-to-create-tooltip-over-text-selection-without-wrapping)
But once again.. despite shareText.css and shareText.js the popup won't render... odd.

Edit2:
Popline seems also to go into the direction I'm looking for:
http://kenshin54.github.io/popline/
=> Doesn't work on Android Webbrowsers...

Edit3:
https://erdembircan.github.io/selection-popup/
Another one that works fine on desktop, but *not* on Android.
Starting to notice a trend here...

Seems like the webpage in this OP, does something entirely different.
Even the "selected" text is hued in their choice of gray text marker.
Huh.

Lost case for non desktop users it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out

```js
(function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) {
    if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
        module.exports = factory();
    else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
        define([], factory);
    else if(typeof exports === 'object')
        exports["TextTip"] = factory();
    else
        root["TextTip"] = factory();
})(window, function() {
return /******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, { enumerable: true, get: getter });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // define __esModule on exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.r = function(exports) {
/******/        if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/        }
/******/        Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // create a fake namespace object
/******/    // mode & 1: value is a module id, require it
/******/    // mode & 2: merge all properties of value into the ns
/******/    // mode & 4: return value when already ns object
/******/    // mode & 8|1: behave like require
/******/    __webpack_require__.t = function(value, mode) {
/******/        if(mode & 1) value = __webpack_require__(value);
/******/        if(mode & 8) return value;
/******/        if((mode & 4) && typeof value === 'object' && value && value.__esModule) return value;
/******/        var ns = Object.create(null);
/******/        __webpack_require__.r(ns);
/******/        Object.defineProperty(ns, 'default', { enumerable: true, value: value });
/******/        if(mode & 2 && typeof value != 'string') for(var key in value) __webpack_require__.d(ns, key, function(key) { return value[key]; }.bind(null, key));
/******/        return ns;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = "./src/TextTip.ts");
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ({

/***/ "./src/TextTip.css":
/*!*************************!*\
  !*** ./src/TextTip.css ***!
  \*************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

// extracted by mini-css-extract-plugin

/***/ }),

/***/ "./src/TextTip.ts":
/*!************************!*\
  !*** ./src/TextTip.ts ***!
  \************************/
/*! exports provided: default */
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export (binding) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, "default", function() { return TextTip; });
/* harmony import */ var _TextTip_css__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./TextTip.css */ "./src/TextTip.css");
/* harmony import */ var _TextTip_css__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_TextTip_css__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__);
function _typeof(obj) { if (typeof Symbol === "function" && typeof Symbol.iterator === "symbol") { _typeof = function _typeof(obj) { return typeof obj; }; } else { _typeof = function _typeof(obj) { return obj && typeof Symbol === "function" && obj.constructor === Symbol && obj !== Symbol.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof obj; }; } return _typeof(obj); }

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

function _defineProperty(obj, key, value) { if (key in obj) { Object.defineProperty(obj, key, { value: value, enumerable: true, configurable: true, writable: true }); } else { obj[key] = value; } return obj; }


var IconFormat;

(function (IconFormat) {
  IconFormat["URL"] = "url";
  IconFormat["SVGSprite"] = "svgsprite";
  IconFormat["Font"] = "font";
})(IconFormat || (IconFormat = {}));

;
;
;

var TextTip = function TextTip(config) {
  var _this = this;

  _classCallCheck(this, TextTip);

  _defineProperty(this, "config", {
    scope: 'body',
    minLength: 1,
    maxLength: Infinity,
    iconFormat: IconFormat.URL,
    buttons: [],
    theme: 'default',
    mobileOSBehaviour: 'hide'
  });

  _defineProperty(this, "scopeEl", void 0);

  _defineProperty(this, "tipEl", void 0);

  _defineProperty(this, "tipWidth", void 0);

  _defineProperty(this, "id", void 0);

  _defineProperty(this, "open", false);

  _defineProperty(this, "isMobileOS", false);

  _defineProperty(this, "_setupScope", function () {
    if (typeof _this.config.scope === 'string') {
      _this.scopeEl = document.querySelector(_this.config.scope);
    }

    if (!_this.scopeEl) {
      throw new Error('TextTip: Cannot find supplied scope');
    }

    _this.scopeEl.setAttribute('data-texttip-scope-id', _this.id.toString());
  });

  _defineProperty(this, "_setupTooltip", function () {
    var inner = document.createElement('div');
    inner.classList.add('texttip__inner');

    _this.config.buttons.forEach(function (btn, index) {
      if (!btn.callback || !btn.icon || !btn.title) {
        throw new Error('TextTip: All buttons should have a callback, icon and title property');
      }

      var btnEl = document.createElement('div');
      btnEl.classList.add('texttip__btn');
      btnEl.setAttribute('role', 'button');
      btnEl.setAttribute('data-texttip-btn-index', index.toString());
      btnEl.style.transitionDelay = 40 * (index + 1) + 'ms';

      switch (_this.config.iconFormat) {
        case IconFormat.URL:
          btnEl.innerHTML = "<img src=\"".concat(btn.icon, "\" alt=\"").concat(btn.title, "\">");
          break;

        case IconFormat.SVGSprite:
          /*
           * The base64 image overlay hack is needed to make the click events work
           * without it the events are swallowed completely for some reason (probably shadow dom related)
           */
          btnEl.innerHTML = "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" title=\"".concat(btn.title, "\" pointer-events=\"none\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<use xlink:href=\"").concat(btn.icon, "\"></use>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</svg>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<img class=\"texttip__btn-cover\" src=\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=\" alt=\"\" aria-hidden=\"true\" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t");
          break;

        case IconFormat.Font:
          btnEl.innerHTML = "<i class=\"".concat(btn.icon, "\" title=\"").concat(btn.title, "\"></i>");
          break;
      }

      inner.appendChild(btnEl);
    });

    var tooltip = document.createElement('div');
    tooltip.classList.add('texttip', 'texttip--theme-' + _this.config.theme);
    tooltip.setAttribute('data-textip-iconformat', _this.config.iconFormat);
    tooltip.setAttribute('data-texttip-id', _this.id.toString());
    tooltip.setAttribute('role', 'tooltip');
    tooltip.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
    tooltip.appendChild(inner);
    document.body.appendChild(tooltip);
    _this.tipEl = tooltip;
    _this.tipWidth = _this.tipEl.offsetWidth;
  });

  _defineProperty(this, "_setupEvents", function () {
    document.addEventListener('selectionchange', _this._onSelectionChanged);

    _this.tipEl.querySelectorAll('.texttip__btn').forEach(function (btn, index) {
      btn.addEventListener('click', _this._onButtonClick);
    });
  });

  _defineProperty(this, "_onSelectionChanged", function (event) {
    if (_this._selectionValid()) {
      _this._updatePosition();

      _this._show();
    } else {
      _this._hide();
    }
  });

  _defineProperty(this, "_selectionValid", function () {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var selStr = selection.toString();
    var selLength = selStr.length;

    if (selLength < _this.config.minLength || selLength > _this.config.maxLength) {
      return false;
    }

    var anchorNodeParent = selection.anchorNode.parentElement;
    var focusNodeParent = selection.focusNode.parentElement;
    if (!anchorNodeParent || !focusNodeParent) return false;
    var anchorParent = anchorNodeParent.closest("[data-texttip-scope-id=\"".concat(_this.id, "\"]"));
    var focusParent = focusNodeParent.closest("[data-texttip-scope-id=\"".concat(_this.id, "\"]")); // Selection must start and end within specified scope

    return !!anchorParent && !!focusParent;
  });

  _defineProperty(this, "_updatePosition", function () {
    var selection = window.getSelection(); // Allows us to measure where the selection is on the page relative to the viewport

    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);

    var _range$getBoundingCli = range.getBoundingClientRect(),
        selTop = _range$getBoundingCli.top,
        selLeft = _range$getBoundingCli.left,
        selWidth = _range$getBoundingCli.width; // Middle of selection width


    var newTipLeft = selLeft + selWidth / 2 - window.scrollX; // Right above selection 

    var newTipBottom = window.innerHeight - selTop - window.scrollY; // Stop tooltip bleeding off of left or right edge of screen
    // Use a buffer of 20px so we don't bump right against the edge
    // The tooltip transforms itself left minus 50% of it's width in css
    // so this will need to be taken into account

    var buffer = 20;
    var tipHalfWidth = _this.tipWidth / 2; // "real" means after taking the css transform into account

    var realTipLeft = newTipLeft - tipHalfWidth;
    var realTipRight = realTipLeft + _this.tipWidth;

    if (realTipLeft < buffer) {
      // Correct for left edge overlap
      newTipLeft = buffer + tipHalfWidth;
    } else if (realTipRight > window.innerWidth - buffer) {
      // Correct for right edge overlap
      newTipLeft = window.innerWidth - buffer - tipHalfWidth;
    }

    _this.tipEl.style.left = newTipLeft + 'px';
    _this.tipEl.style.bottom = newTipBottom + 'px';
  });

  _defineProperty(this, "_onButtonClick", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    var btn = event.currentTarget;
    var btnIndex = parseInt(btn.getAttribute('data-texttip-btn-index'), 10);
    var selection = window.getSelection();

    _this.config.buttons[btnIndex].callback(selection.toString());
  });

  _defineProperty(this, "_show", function () {
    if (_this.open) return;
    _this.open = true;

    _this.tipEl.classList.add('texttip--show');

    _this.tipEl.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true'); // Callback


    if (_this.config.on && typeof _this.config.on.show === 'function') _this.config.on.show();
  });

  _defineProperty(this, "_hide", function () {
    if (!_this.open) return;
    _this.open = false;

    _this.tipEl.classList.remove('texttip--show');

    _this.tipEl.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'false'); // Callback


    if (_this.config.on && typeof _this.config.on.hide === 'function') _this.config.on.hide();
  });

  if (typeof window.getSelection === 'undefined') {
    throw new Error('TextTip: Selection api not supported in this browser');
  }

  if (_typeof(config) !== 'object') {
    throw new Error('TextTip: No config supplied');
  }

  Object.assign(this.config, config);

  if (typeof config.buttons === 'undefined') {
    throw new Error('TextTip: No buttons supplied');
  }

  this.isMobileOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
  this.id = TextTip._getID(); // Hide on mobile OS's, they have their own conflicting tooltips

  if (this.config.mobileOSBehaviour === 'hide' && this.isMobileOS) return;

  this._setupScope();

  this._setupTooltip();

  this._setupEvents();
};

_defineProperty(TextTip, "instanceCount", 0);

_defineProperty(TextTip, "_getID", function () {
  return ++TextTip.instanceCount;
});


;

/***/ })

/******/ })["default"];
});
//# sourceMappingURL=TextTip.js.map
           const tip3 = new TextTip({
                    scope: '.scope-three',
                    iconFormat: 'font',
                    buttons: [
                        {title: 'Copy and paste', icon: 'fa fa-copy', callback: console.log},
                        {title: 'Share', icon: 'fa fa-share-square', callback: console.log},
                        {title: 'Favourite', icon: 'fa fa-heart', callback: console.log},
                        {title: 'Like', icon: 'fa fa-thumbs-up', callback: console.log}
                    ]
                });
```

```css
        .texttip {
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    background: #fff;
    transform: translate(-50%, -12px);
    transition: none;
    opacity: 0; 
}

.texttip--theme-default {
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);
    transform: translate(-50%, -34px);
    border: 2px solid #000;
}

.texttip--theme-default::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 100%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 6px 9px 0 9px;
    border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.texttip--show {
    pointer-events: auto;
    transform: translate(-50%, -12px);
    opacity: 1;
}

.texttip--theme-default.texttip--show {
    transition: opacity .3s, transform .3s;
}

.texttip__inner {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.texttip--theme-default .texttip__inner {
    border-radius: 7px;
}

.texttip__btn {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: .4em;
    transition: none;
    background: #fff;
}

.texttip--theme-default .texttip__btn {
    transform: translate(0, 1.5em);
}

.texttip--theme-default .texttip__btn:hover {
    background: #00e3f4;
}

.texttip--theme-default.texttip--show .texttip__btn {
    transition-property: transform;
    transition-duration: 200ms;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.texttip__btn-cover {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.texttip__btn:last-child {
    margin: 0;
}

.texttip[data-textip-iconformat="url"] img {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: 1.5em;
}

.texttip[data-textip-iconformat="svgsprite"] svg {
    display: block;
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 1.5em;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.texttip[data-textip-iconformat="font"] i {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="scope-three" style="padding-top:3em;">
            
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit id temporibus dolorum soluta laboriosam, repellat ipsam facere cumque consequatur. Eos et libero sapiente mollitia accusantium impedit commodi incidunt, accusamus esse.</p>
            
        </section>
```

Comment: One note though: This works very well on desktop browsers. But seems to be struggling on mobile webbrowsers (like Android) regrettably.. (Then again popline doesn't work there either...). Kinda weird how that website in the OP works on everything...

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script>
(function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) {
    if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
        module.exports = factory();
    else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
        define([], factory);
    else if(typeof exports === 'object')
        exports["TextTip"] = factory();a
    else
        root["TextTip"] = factory();
})(window, function() {
return /******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, { enumerable: true, get: getter });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // define __esModule on exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.r = function(exports) {
/******/        if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/        }
/******/        Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // create a fake namespace object
/******/    // mode & 1: value is a module id, require it
/******/    // mode & 2: merge all properties of value into the ns
/******/    // mode & 4: return value when already ns object
/******/    // mode & 8|1: behave like require
/******/    __webpack_require__.t = function(value, mode) {
/******/        if(mode & 1) value = __webpack_require__(value);
/******/        if(mode & 8) return value;
/******/        if((mode & 4) && typeof value === 'object' && value && value.__esModule) return value;
/******/        var ns = Object.create(null);
/******/        __webpack_require__.r(ns);
/******/        Object.defineProperty(ns, 'default', { enumerable: true, value: value });
/******/        if(mode & 2 && typeof value != 'string') for(var key in value) __webpack_require__.d(ns, key, function(key) { return value[key]; }.bind(null, key));
/******/        return ns;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = "./src/TextTip.ts");
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ({

/***/ "./src/TextTip.css":
/*!*************************!*\
  !*** ./src/TextTip.css ***!
  \*************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

// extracted by mini-css-extract-plugin

/***/ }),

/***/ "./src/TextTip.ts":
/*!************************!*\
  !*** ./src/TextTip.ts ***!
  \************************/
/*! exports provided: default */
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export (binding) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, "default", function() { return TextTip; });
/* harmony import */ var _TextTip_css__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./TextTip.css */ "./src/TextTip.css");
/* harmony import */ var _TextTip_css__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_TextTip_css__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__);
function _typeof(obj) { if (typeof Symbol === "function" && typeof Symbol.iterator === "symbol") { _typeof = function _typeof(obj) { return typeof obj; }; } else { _typeof = function _typeof(obj) { return obj && typeof Symbol === "function" && obj.constructor === Symbol && obj !== Symbol.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof obj; }; } return _typeof(obj); }

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

function _defineProperty(obj, key, value) { if (key in obj) { Object.defineProperty(obj, key, { value: value, enumerable: true, configurable: true, writable: true }); } else { obj[key] = value; } return obj; }


var IconFormat;

(function (IconFormat) {
  IconFormat["URL"] = "url";
  IconFormat["SVGSprite"] = "svgsprite";
  IconFormat["Font"] = "font";
})(IconFormat || (IconFormat = {}));

;
;
;

var TextTip = function TextTip(config) {
  var _this = this;

  _classCallCheck(this, TextTip);

  _defineProperty(this, "config", {
    scope: 'body',
    minLength: 1,
    maxLength: Infinity,
    iconFormat: IconFormat.URL,
    buttons: [],
    theme: 'default',
    mobileOSBehaviour: 'hide'
  });

  _defineProperty(this, "scopeEl", void 0);

  _defineProperty(this, "tipEl", void 0);

  _defineProperty(this, "tipWidth", void 0);

  _defineProperty(this, "id", void 0);

  _defineProperty(this, "open", false);

  _defineProperty(this, "isMobileOS", false);

  _defineProperty(this, "_setupScope", function () {
    if (typeof _this.config.scope === 'string') {
      _this.scopeEl = document.querySelector(_this.config.scope);
    }

    if (!_this.scopeEl) {
      throw new Error('TextTip: Cannot find supplied scope');
    }

    _this.scopeEl.setAttribute('data-texttip-scope-id', _this.id.toString());
  });

  _defineProperty(this, "_setupTooltip", function () {
    var inner = document.createElement('div');
    inner.classList.add('texttip__inner');

    _this.config.buttons.forEach(function (btn, index) {
      if (!btn.callback || !btn.icon || !btn.title) {
        throw new Error('TextTip: All buttons should have a callback, icon and title property');
      }

      var btnEl = document.createElement('div');
      btnEl.classList.add('texttip__btn');
      btnEl.setAttribute('role', 'button');
      btnEl.setAttribute('data-texttip-btn-index', index.toString());
      btnEl.style.transitionDelay = 40 * (index + 1) + 'ms';

      switch (_this.config.iconFormat) {
        case IconFormat.URL:
          btnEl.innerHTML = "<img src=\"".concat(btn.icon, "\" alt=\"").concat(btn.title, "\">");
          break;

        case IconFormat.SVGSprite:
          /*
           * The base64 image overlay hack is needed to make the click events work
           * without it the events are swallowed completely for some reason (probably shadow dom related)
           */
          btnEl.innerHTML = "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" title=\"".concat(btn.title, "\" pointer-events=\"none\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<use xlink:href=\"").concat(btn.icon, "\"></use>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</svg>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<img class=\"texttip__btn-cover\" src=\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=\" alt=\"\" aria-hidden=\"true\" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t");
          break;

        case IconFormat.Font:
          btnEl.innerHTML = "<i class=\"".concat(btn.icon, "\" title=\"").concat(btn.title, "\"></i>");
          break;
      }

      inner.appendChild(btnEl);
    });

    var tooltip = document.createElement('div');
    tooltip.classList.add('texttip', 'texttip--theme-' + _this.config.theme);
    tooltip.setAttribute('data-textip-iconformat', _this.config.iconFormat);
    tooltip.setAttribute('data-texttip-id', _this.id.toString());
    tooltip.setAttribute('role', 'tooltip');
    tooltip.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
    tooltip.appendChild(inner);
    document.body.appendChild(tooltip);
    _this.tipEl = tooltip;
    _this.tipWidth = _this.tipEl.offsetWidth;
  });

  _defineProperty(this, "_setupEvents", function () {
    document.addEventListener('selectionchange', _this._onSelectionChanged);

    _this.tipEl.querySelectorAll('.texttip__btn').forEach(function (btn, index) {
      btn.addEventListener('click', _this._onButtonClick);
    });
  });

  _defineProperty(this, "_onSelectionChanged", function (event) {
    if (_this._selectionValid()) {
      _this._updatePosition();

      _this._show();
    } else {
      _this._hide();
    }
  });

  _defineProperty(this, "_selectionValid", function () {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var selStr = selection.toString();
    var selLength = selStr.length;

    if (selLength < _this.config.minLength || selLength > _this.config.maxLength) {
      return false;
    }

    var anchorNodeParent = selection.anchorNode.parentElement;
    var focusNodeParent = selection.focusNode.parentElement;
    if (!anchorNodeParent || !focusNodeParent) return false;
    var anchorParent = anchorNodeParent.closest("[data-texttip-scope-id=\"".concat(_this.id, "\"]"));
    var focusParent = focusNodeParent.closest("[data-texttip-scope-id=\"".concat(_this.id, "\"]")); // Selection must start and end within specified scope

    return !!anchorParent && !!focusParent;
  });

  _defineProperty(this, "_updatePosition", function () {
    var selection = window.getSelection(); // Allows us to measure where the selection is on the page relative to the viewport

    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);

    var _range$getBoundingCli = range.getBoundingClientRect(),
        selTop = _range$getBoundingCli.top,
        selLeft = _range$getBoundingCli.left,
        selWidth = _range$getBoundingCli.width; // Middle of selection width


    var newTipLeft = selLeft + selWidth / 2 - window.scrollX; // Right above selection 

    var newTipBottom = window.innerHeight - selTop - window.scrollY; // Stop tooltip bleeding off of left or right edge of screen
    // Use a buffer of 20px so we don't bump right against the edge
    // The tooltip transforms itself left minus 50% of it's width in css
    // so this will need to be taken into account

    var buffer = 20;
    var tipHalfWidth = _this.tipWidth / 2; // "real" means after taking the css transform into account

    var realTipLeft = newTipLeft - tipHalfWidth;
    var realTipRight = realTipLeft + _this.tipWidth;

    if (realTipLeft < buffer) {
      // Correct for left edge overlap
      newTipLeft = buffer + tipHalfWidth;
    } else if (realTipRight > window.innerWidth - buffer) {
      // Correct for right edge overlap
      newTipLeft = window.innerWidth - buffer - tipHalfWidth;
    }

    _this.tipEl.style.left = newTipLeft + 'px';
    _this.tipEl.style.bottom = newTipBottom + 'px';
  });

  _defineProperty(this, "_onButtonClick", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    var btn = event.currentTarget;
    var btnIndex = parseInt(btn.getAttribute('data-texttip-btn-index'), 10);
    var selection = window.getSelection();

    _this.config.buttons[btnIndex].callback(selection.toString());
  });

  _defineProperty(this, "_show", function () {
    if (_this.open) return;
    _this.open = true;

    _this.tipEl.classList.add('texttip--show');

    _this.tipEl.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true'); // Callback


    if (_this.config.on && typeof _this.config.on.show === 'function') _this.config.on.show();
  });

  _defineProperty(this, "_hide", function () {
    if (!_this.open) return;
    _this.open = false;

    _this.tipEl.classList.remove('texttip--show');

    _this.tipEl.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'false'); // Callback


    if (_this.config.on && typeof _this.config.on.hide === 'function') _this.config.on.hide();
  });

  if (typeof window.getSelection === 'undefined') {
    throw new Error('TextTip: Selection api not supported in this browser');
  }

  if (_typeof(config) !== 'object') {
    throw new Error('TextTip: No config supplied');
  }

  Object.assign(this.config, config);

  if (typeof config.buttons === 'undefined') {
    throw new Error('TextTip: No buttons supplied');
  }

  this.isMobileOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
  this.id = TextTip._getID(); // Hide on mobile OS's, they have their own conflicting tooltips

  if (this.config.mobileOSBehaviour === 'hide' && this.isMobileOS) return;

  this._setupScope();

  this._setupTooltip();

  this._setupEvents();
};

_defineProperty(TextTip, "instanceCount", 0);

_defineProperty(TextTip, "_getID", function () {
  return ++TextTip.instanceCount;
});


;

/***/ })

/******/ })["default"];
});
//# sourceMappingURL=TextTip.js.map


</script>
<style>
.texttip {
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    background: #fff;
    transform: translate(-50%, -12px);
    transition: none;
    opacity: 0; 
}

.texttip--theme-default {
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);
    transform: translate(-50%, -34px);
    border: 2px solid #000;
}

.texttip--theme-default::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 100%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 6px 9px 0 9px;
    border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.texttip--show {
    pointer-events: auto;
    transform: translate(-50%, -12px);
    opacity: 1;
}

.texttip--theme-default.texttip--show {
    transition: opacity .3s, transform .3s;
}

.texttip__inner {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.texttip--theme-default .texttip__inner {
    border-radius: 7px;
}

.texttip__btn {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: .4em;
    transition: none;
    background: #fff;
}

.texttip--theme-default .texttip__btn {
    transform: translate(0, 1.5em);
}

.texttip--theme-default .texttip__btn:hover {
    background: #00e3f4;
}

.texttip--theme-default.texttip--show .texttip__btn {
    transition-property: transform;
    transition-duration: 200ms;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.texttip__btn-cover {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.texttip__btn:last-child {
    margin: 0;
}

.texttip[data-textip-iconformat="url"] img {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: 1.5em;
}

.texttip[data-textip-iconformat="svgsprite"] svg {
    display: block;
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 1.5em;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.texttip[data-textip-iconformat="font"] i {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}



</style>
</head>
<body>

        <section class="scope-three" style="padding-top:3em;">
            
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit id temporibus dolorum soluta laboriosam, repellat ipsam facere cumque consequatur. Eos et libero sapiente mollitia accusantium impedit commodi incidunt, accusamus esse.</p>
            
        </section>
<script>
                const tip3 = new TextTip({
                    scope: '.scope-three',
                    iconFormat: 'font',
                    buttons: [
                        {title: 'Copy and paste', icon: 'fa fa-copy', callback: console.log},
                        {title: 'Share', icon: 'fa fa-share-square', callback: console.log},
                        {title: 'Favourite', icon: 'fa fa-heart', callback: console.log},
                        {title: 'Like', icon: 'fa fa-thumbs-up', callback: console.log}
                    ]
                });
            </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: yo can make another js file for script code and add to the link

Comment: I pasted this entire block into an html file and rendered in my browser, no tooltip/hover shows at the cursor tho. Any specific  browser requirements ?. The site mentioned worked in any of my browsers.

Comment: i make a new snnipet for you please check it out.and this will work on every browser.try with selecting text